# Why don't I have to decode/parse a JSON string generated by PHP in JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

To use some variables in a JS script, I simply set them in a wrapper with JSON, like so:

```
<?php // Variables for JS
$vars = array(
    'fetchPath' => "$home/my-url.php",
);
?>
<script>
var phpVars = <?php echo json_encode($vars); ?>;
</script>
```

This results in

```
<script>
var phpVars = {"fetchPath":"http:\/\/my.website.com\/my-url.php"};
</script>
```

Now, when I try to parse this value from a JS script, I get an unexpected token error. But, when I simply use the variable as if it were an object, it works perfectly. In other words, I can simply access `phpVars.fetchPath` without having converted that value back to an object representation.

Am I completely losing my mind after hours of working with Perl, PHP, and Javascript, and you don't have to decode a JSON string in JS - or is something else going on?

Comment: Stop guessing and hit Ctrl+U (*View Source*) to see the generated JavaScript code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález How would that help me?

Comment: look the generated javascript variable from php with view source

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion. If you prefer to keep an air of mystery around computers and think that *unexpected token error* is just the will of an almighty God... ;-P

Comment: Maybe `$home` encoded before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
<script>
var phpVars = <?php echo json_encode($vars); ?>;
</script>
```

you're generating JavaScript code with PHP. So what actually goes to your browser is:

```
<script>
var phpVars = /*...THE_JSON_GOES_HERE...*/;
</script>
```

Note that it's not in quotes or anything. Your example code will produce a JSON string that looks something like `{"fetchPath":"/path/to/my-url.php"}`, so what the browser would see is:

```
<script>
var phpVars = {"fetchPath":"http:\/\/my.website.com\my-url.php"};
</script>
```

Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript object initializer syntax, that's perfectly valid JavaScript code. The parser parsing the script tag contents parses it as *code*, not as JSON. But that's fine, because as long as it's used as a right-hand value (e.g., on the right-hand side of `=` or passed into a function, etc.), JSON is valid JavaScript.

Comment: Same question as I asked Stefan, in which cases, then, do you need [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) / [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: When JavaScript has access to actual JSON, e.g.: `var phpVars = '{"fetchPath":"/path/to/my-url.php"}';`

Comment: @BramVanroy: In this case, you don't; the parser that handled the script tag has already parsed it. If you were retrieving that same text *as text* (for instance, in the response of an ajax call), you'd have to parse it, because it would just be text. But just like you don't have to manually parse the HTML of the page (the browser is *already* running an HTML parser on it), you don't haev to manually parse the content of `script` tags (the browser is *already* running a JavaScript parser on it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, that makes sense! I guess that's where my confusion was: how can the browser distinguish between some string I assign to a variable in a script tag, and some JSON (that needs to be parsed) that I get from a GET request. And, as you pointed out, the answer is that the JS parser that runs over the script tag already did that parsing. Correct?

Comment: @BramVanroy: Yup, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

That's what JSON is all about: it's the [JavaScript Object Notation](http://www.json.org) - a format that's being natively understood by JavaScript.

```
var json = {"a": 1, "b": false, "c": null, "d": [1, 2, 3], "e": {"f": 1}};
```

is perfectly valid JavaScript and that's what the PHP `json_encode` function produces out of the following structure for example:

```
$json = array(
    'a' => 1, 
    'b' => false, 
    'c' => null, 
    'd' => array(1, 2, 3), 
    'e' => array(
        'f' => 1
    )
);
```

You'd need `parseJSON` if you retrieve the **string** `'{"a": 1, "b": false, "c": null, "d": [1, 2, 3], "e": {"f": 1}}'` from an XMLHttpRequest (aka AJAX) request. The response body will be a string and this needs to be converted into a JavaScript object by using `parseJSON`. That's just one example. Opening a JSON file in nodejs is another one.

In your example you literally embedded the `json_encode` output into some JavaScript source (defined by the `<script>`tags). That's why the JavaScript interpreter catches up the JSON-syntax and constructs a JavaScript object from it.

Comment: In which cases, then, do you need [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) / [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: No, you don't. `JSON.parse` means transform a String into a JavaScript object (JSON). `{foo: "bar"}` is not the same as `'{foo: "bar"}'`. One is an object, the other is a String. `JSON.parse('{foo: "bar"}')` would return `{foo: "bar"}`.

Comment: @BramVanroy for instance useful in _nodejs_ if you need to read and parse a file.

Answer (score 0):

JSON was modeled after the syntax for JavaScript literals.

When you take some JSON and drop it into the middle of a JavaScript program as if it were JavaScript code, then it is treated as JavaScript code and parsed as a set of JavaScript literals.

> In which cases, then, do you need parseJSON

When you get JSON in a format that is not JavaScript code (such as when you fetch a JSON resource over HTTP with XMLHttpRequest), it is put in a string. You need to convert the JSON into JavaScript objects explicitly then.

Answer (score 0):

A few terms that are not always clear:

- **PHP and JavaScript** are different languages and do not interact directly: they don't share variables, they don't share resources of any kind... they don't even run on the same computer! PHP runs on the server (let's say, a DELL computer somewhere in Google data center in Ireland) and JavaScript runs inside the browser (let's say, granny's laptop near Munich).

  You often use PHP to generate JavaScript code. The browser doesn't know or care about how that code is generated: it merely sees the generated source code—and show should you: with your browser's *View Source* feature (typically mapped to the<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> short-cut).
- **JavaScript and JSON** are different languages and could hardly have less capabilities in common. JavaScript is a programming language and JSON is a data format. The only relation is that JSON creator has the idea of basing his language in a (very limited) subset of the JavaScript syntax. That witty idea allowed to read properly formatted JSON from JavaScript code by using the `eval()` function—in other words, he invented a new format and he didn't have to write a parser!

  *(Of course, nobody uses `eval()` any more and as JSON became popular everybody has written proper parsers anyway.)*

And one more detail... The [PHP function to generate JSON](http://php.net/json_encode) actually allows to generate *partial JSON*, which technically speaking is not valid JSON:

```
echo json_encode(array('A', 'B')); // Valid JSON: ["A","B"]
echo json_encode('Leopoldo Alas "Clarín"'); // JSON fragment: "Leopoldo Alas \"Clar\u00edn\""
```

That trick is often "abused" to inject raw input into generated JavaScript code because there's otherwise no simple way to avoid causing parse errors if your data happens to contain characters that have a special meaning inside JavaScript syntax:

```
<?php
$writer = 'Leopoldo Alas "Clarín"';
?>
var writer = "<?php echo $writer; ?>";
```

```
var writer = "Leopoldo Alas "Clarín"";
                             ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at node.js:544:27
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

## You are not using quotes

This is first parsed by PHP, server side, so whatever is within php tags will be rendered and returned to the browser (which is the one that parses javascript):

```
<script>
var phpVars = <?php echo json_encode($vars); ?>;
</script>
```

The resulting text, ON THE BROWSER would be:

```
<script>
var phpVars = {"foo": "bar"};
</script>
```

#### If you were using quotes...

```
<script>
var phpVars = <?php echo "'" . json_encode($vars) . "'" ; ?>;
</script>
```

That would turn into the following html on the browser:

```
<script>
var phpVars = '{"foo": "bar"}';
</script>
```

Then in the above case you would need to parse the result because is just simply a string:

```
<script>
var phpVars = '{"foo": "bar"}';
vars = JSON.parse(phpVars);
//vars is now a JS valid object
</script>
```

So the answer is that your php is echoing a text that will not be actually represented a string in JS but as an object notation object. [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is used to process a string representation of a valid JS value (an array, an object, number, etc.)